# Specifying Spring profile on command line in Spring Boot Multimodule Mave project

Tags: java, spring-boot, command-line-arguments, multi-module, maven-profiles

I've got [this](https://github.com/RichardBenes/spring-profile-issues) multi-module Spring Boot (v2.7.0) project.
It's fairly bare-bone - one Controller with one endpoint.

```
├───app
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └───src
│       └───main
│           └───java
│               └───com
│                   └───rb
│                       └─── App.java
├───controller
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └───src
│       └───main
│           └───java
│               └───com
│                   └───rb
│                       └─── MainController.java
└ pom.xml
```

I'm using Maven 3.8.4.

I would like to specify profile on the command line using this [Spring Boot's nice shortcut](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#run.examples.specify-active-profiles):

```
mvn clean install; 
mvn spring-boot:run '-Dspring-boot.run.profiles=local' --projects app
```

*(I'm running it from PowerShell, hence the single quotes around the parameter)*

However, it doesn't work. The app starts, runs fine, but with the `default` profile.

**My question is - how to make this nice syntax work, or why does it not work?**

This uglier [longer syntax](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#run) mentioned in Spring's works:

```
mvn clean install;
mvn spring-boot:run '-Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Dspring.profiles.active=local"' --projects app
```

I also tried running it on Command Prompt omitting those single-quotes - with the same result.

I would appreciate any insights on what could be the issue - I'm no expert in Java's
properties & command-line arguments.

Answer (score 2):

When you run with the spring-boot maven plugin, you have to pass it like this

`mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=local`

Comment: Thank you for answer, but this does not work - at least not for me. Did it work for you in that project? If so, then the issue could be with my instalation or something.